# Does the Knight bus actually move continuously on the roads, or does it teleport/apparate?

Tags: harry-potter, knight-bus

When describing Knight Bus movements, there's frequently a "`BANG`", followed by a bus being elsewhere.

Is it elaborated anywhere in canon explicitly whether the bus merely speeds up, or does it actually apparate long distance to reach its destination?

I'm specifically interested in apparating long distance, not - if there are any - short jumps to get over small obstacles like other cars, houses, or curbs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the Knight Bus engages in some sort of Apparition-like magic when it transports itself around the country.

> *BANG*.
>   Chairs slid backwards again as the Knight Bus jumped from the Birmingham motorway to a quiet country lane full of hairpin bends. Hedgerows on either side of the road were leaping out of their way as they mounted the verges. From here they moved to a main street in the middle of a busy town, then to a viaduct surrounded by tall hills, then to a windswept road between high-rise flats, each time with a loud *BANG*.
>   *Order of the Phoenix* - chapter 24 - *Occlumency*

I think the Knight Bus relies on Apparition, unusually fast speed for a vehicle of its size and structure, invisibility (via Disillusionment Charm perhaps?) as it seems to appear from thin air, and on the oblivious nature of Muggles, to avoid detection.

> There was another tremendous *BANG*, and next moment Harry found himself flat on his bed, thrown backwards by the speed of the Knight Bus. Pulling himself up, Harry stared out of the dark window and saw that they were now bowling along a completely different street. Stan was watching Harry’s stunned face with great enjoyment.
>   ‘This is where we was before you flagged us down,’ he said. ‘Where are we, Ern? Somewhere in Wales?’
>   ‘Ar,’ said Ernie.
>   ‘How come the Muggles don’t hear the bus?’ said Harry.
>   ‘Them!’ said Stan contemptuously. ‘Don’ listen properly, do they? Don’ look properly either. Never notice nuffink, they don’.’
>   *Prisoner of Azkaban* - chapter 3 - *The Knight Bus*

Even though Harry is thrown backward for only "a moment," in a blink of an eye the bus is gone from Privet Drive and back in Wales. To me this indicates some kind of instant transportation like Apparition. Or perhaps the Portus Charm is used (Portus is what creates a Portkey) or the fundamental magic behind a spell like Portus.

Comment: Sounds like the Knight Bus could do with some inertial dampeners.

Answer (score 1):

When Harry first got on, the bus did appear out of nowhere. Then right after they pick Harry up, it jumps to Whales. So the bus can jump from one spot to another. However, it seems it returned to the same spot it was before. So it can only momentarily jump from one spot to the next, and only to pick up passengers, it seems.

Comment: That's not true.  In the Order of the Phoenix, Harry and the Weasleys all take the Knight Bus back to Hogwarts after Christmas, and it's clearly jumping from one spot to another as it goes along it's route.  it certainly appears to be doing *something* akin to apparation, but instead of twisting and turning, there's a definite physical lurch, as if it accelerates and decelerates rapidly.  It seems more like a Star Wars jump to hyperspace if you ask me.

Comment: @David - that specific scene was precisely what arose the question for me. I couldn't quite figure out if BANGs in it were teleportation or not

Comment: @DVK: Not sure if it matters if it is teleportation, or extremely quick physical transportation. Both have similar characteristics...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - I'm not sure what you mean by "extremely quick physical transportation"? If something like super-fast-driving, it matters. If "hyperspace", then no, it's in the "teleportation" class of moving as far as my interest

Comment: @DVK: The bus is in one spot one moment, there is a bang, and it is in a completely different location. Even if it technically moved along the road that entire way, it may as well be teleportation.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - the difference is whether there WAS a road for it to move on. I care less about the bus but about what it meant for road continuity.