# What happens if Knight Bus is involved in a collision?

Tags: harry-potter, knight-bus

In the movies, we see the Knight Bus to be bending, swerving and squeezing with a switch used by the driver, to avoid collision with other objects like people, other vehicles, etc.

It is also invisible so I want to learn what happens if it accidentally makes a collision? Couldn't find anything about this subject.

Reading the question [*Does the Knight bus actually move continuously on the roads, or does it teleport/apparate?*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/does-the-knight-bus-actually-move-continuously-on-the-roads-or-does-it-teleport), I can understand that it can teleport for transport, but I mean when not teleporting and when it is manually being driven, what would be the outcome of a collision is there example for it? (Like reversing what happened, memory wipes, or will be just a crash)

Comment: You kind of answered your own question.

Comment: But like I said, it is moving on the road, not always teleporting and I don't think there is 0% chance of an accident.

Comment: It doesn't collide with anything, [because magic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5073/31394). We don't know what safeguards might be in place in case it ever did.

Comment: @randal'thor Still can't believe that meme is considered as an accepted explanation. But why not... **Because magic.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the books it's rather the reverse - the Knight Bus doesn't swerve around things, *things move out of the Knight Buses way*.

> Ernie didn't seem to have mastered the use of a steering wheel. The
>   Knight Bus kept mounting the pavement, but it didn't hit anything;
>   lines of lamp posts, letter-boxes, and bins **jumped out of its way** as
>   it approached and back into position once it had passed.

Later, at the mention of Voldemort...

> Even Stan's pimples went white; Ern jerked the steering wheel **so hard
>   that a whole farmhouse had to jump aside to avoid the bus**.

So as ever this is the movies getting things wrong. What would happen if the Knight Bus crashed? We don't know, since as long as it's functional, **it can't crash**.

Comment: +1 for "as ever this is the movies getting things wrong."

Comment: thank you for the not "because magic" answer and trying to really give an answer to the question. What I wanted to learn is what was happening in the books and you explained it.